# UIButton border along rounded rect

Tags: objective-c

I have a button and its type is UIButtonTypeRoundedRect, but its border does not go along the rounded corner. How can I curve the border.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Images are the recommended method for creating custom buttons.  Apple's built-in buttons are basically only there for prototyping.

You could also create a subclass of UIButton and then override the methods for `drawInRect` and provide custom drawing code, probably using CoreGraphics.  However, it is still much cleaner in code and more efficient at runtime to just use images.

Answer (score 5):

Check out this blog post I recently wrote: [UI Polish in An Instant](http://blog.hawkimedia.com/2011/11/ui-polish-in-an-instant/)

You're on the right track accessing the button's layer property, but there is more you need to do (for example, to get rounded corners, add `deleteButton1.layer.cornerRadius = 10`), and more you can do, all without extra images.

Comment: Using `.layer` effects can become very processing-intensive when applied to places like TableViews where the effect is called many times.  This results in degraded battery performance, as well as having limited flexibility in regards to design changes and causes more cluttered code.  While Quartz is capable of lots of neat effects, as soon as your client asks for a button that looks a certain way that you can't model in Quartz, you'll have to scrap all of your finely-tweaked code in favor of images, anyway.